# Run your app in Android Studio by connecting it to Actual Device or through APK

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it better to test your application via USB (directly connecting your phone to the Android Studio) or by downloading the APK version of your app. I've been using emulator and it's really time consuming because it keeps lagging on my laptop. I wanna know which is faster and safer?

Comment: You need to use the emulator if you don't have a device with specific api. But at the end of the day you need to test your application with real devices. 
For sake of simplicity, you can use plugin for testing your app via WiFi. Try WiFi ADB plugin for Android Studio.

Comment: I haven't try it via WiFi but I might consider it as well. Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting your phone via USB is always a more reliable and faster option (even if u don't consider the time it takes to copy and paste your APK file from pc to phone) You can also do a activity restart rather than restarting whole app this way[image] which is less time consuming. You can even specify a certain activity to launch for testing. It also provides lots of Monitoring options like device monitoring, Network Monitoring, Database Inspection, Layout Inspection and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this, I decided to rely on USB now.